# PrimeNG dropdown with span

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I need to create simple form, with text and dropdowns. I managed to deal with textInput but I can't do the same for dropdowns.

Here is my code

```
 <div class="p-grid p-dir-col p-offset-2">

      <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
        <div class="ui-md-10">
          <div class="ui-inputgroup">
            <span class="ui-inputgroup-addon" style="width:280px">Text</span>
            <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="abcdef">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
        <div class="ui-md-10">
          <div class="ui-inputgroup">                
            <span class="ui-inputgroup-addon" style="width:280px">Dropdown</span>
            <p-dropdown [options]="options" optionLabel="value"></p-dropdown>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</div>
```

And here is how it looks like... I'd like to have equal width span and equal width input/dropdown next to it. But dropdown refuses to do so.

[image]

## edit

```
  <div class="p-grid p-dir-col p-offset-2">

      <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
        <div class="p-col p-md-10">
          <div class="ui-inputgroup" fxLayout="row">
            <div fxFlex class="p-col p-md-4">
              <span class="ui-inputgroup-addon" style="width:100%">Text</span>
            </div>
            <div fxFlex class="p-col p-md-8">
              <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="abcdef">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
        <div class="p-col p-md-10">
          <div class="ui-inputgroup" fxLayout="row">
            <div fxFlex class="p-col p-md-4">
              <span class="ui-inputgroup-addon" style="width:100%">Dropdown</span>
            </div>
            <div fxFlex class="p-col p-md-8">
              <p-dropdown [options]="options" optionLabel="value"></p-dropdown>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div
```

Looks better, but Id like span to stick to input/dropdown. Also, margin between rows is a bit too big.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flex Layout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/flex-layout)

```
<div class="p-grid p-dir-col p-offset-2">

  <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
    <div class="ui-md-10">
      <div class="ui-inputgroup" fxLayout="row">
        <div fxFlex><span class="ui-inputgroup-addon" style="width:280px">Text</span></div>
        <div fxFlex><input type="text" pInputText placeholder="abcdef"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
    <div class="ui-md-10">
      <div class="ui-inputgroup" fxLayout="row">                
        <div fxFlex><span class="ui-inputgroup-addon" style="width:280px">Dropdown</span></div>
        <div fxFlex><p-dropdown [options]="options" optionLabel="value"></p-dropdown></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have not tested the code. You may need to play a little with it.

Comment: Thanks, It works a bit better, still got a bit troubles with that. Edited my question with more info.

Comment: @JohnDoe, I think you don't need the css 'width: 280px'. If it's not okay, can you share your project at https://stackblitz.com/ ? I can make sure it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
    <div class="p-col p-md-10">
      <div class="ui-inputgroup" fxLayout="row">
        <div fxFlex class="p-col p-md-4">
          <span class="ui-inputgroup-addon" style="width:100%">Text</span>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex class="p-col p-md-8">
          <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="abcdef">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
    <div class="p-col p-md-10">
      <div class="ui-inputgroup" fxLayout="row">
        <div fxFlex class="p-col p-md-4">
          <span class="ui-inputgroup-addon" style="width:100%">Dropdown</span>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex class="p-col p-md-8">
          <p-dropdown [options]="options" optionLabel="value"></p-dropdown>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div
```